# @RequestParam is still giving null even when is not required

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-rest

I have a controller with one param:

```
@GetMapping("/people")
    public Page<People> list(
            @RequestParam(name="name", required = false) String name
            Pageable pageable
            ){

        Page<People> peoples=PeopleService.findByName(pageable,name);
        return peoples;

    }
```

When I go to `localhost:8080/people?name=John`, it is giving me right data, but when I go to `localhost:8080/people`, it is giving me no data, but I want it to give me all people.

I found that it is caused by Spring, it is still searching `where name=null`.

How to solve this problem because I have more parameters like age,date etc?

Comment: Why not using different URL's then? e.g. `/people/all` for all people

Comment: Because you are still calling the `findByName` method. If the parameter is `null` and you want to return everything use `findAll`. You will need some logic in the controller for that.

Comment: Is it JPA service?

Comment: You probably also wants to add a comma after your 'name' parameter and rename your 'peoples' variable to 'people'.

Answer (score 0):

You are calling method `findByName` with `name` parameter which is not required. Check if the name variable is empty or not and depending on that call `findByName` or `findAll` method.

```
@GetMapping("/people")
    public Page<People> list(
            @RequestParam(name="name", required = false) String name
            Pageable pageable
            ){
        if(name != null){

        Page<People> peoples=PeopleService.findByName(pageable,name);
        return peoples;

        }else{

        Page<People> peoples=PeopleService.findAll(pageable);
        return peoples;

        }

    }
```

Comment: This code will break with a `NullPointerException` when `name` is empty.

Comment: @M.Deinum then checking against `null` instead of comparing to empty string should work?

Comment: You can leverage Apache Commons StringUtils.isEmpty(str) , which checks for empty strings and handles null gracefully

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Specifications`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#specifications) in `Spring Data`.

Just make your `PeopleService` interface (if it's your spring data repository interface) extends `JpaSpecificationExecutor< People >` and create a class like `PeopleSpecification` which implements `Specification< People >` like this:

```
public class PeopleSpecification implements Specification<People> {

    private String firstName;

    //getters and setters

    public Predicate toPredicate(Root<People> root, CriteriaQuery<?> query, CriteriaBuilder cb) {
        if (firstName != null)
            return cb.equal(root.get("firstName"), firstName);
        return cb.and();
    }
}
```

Then change your controller method to get an instance of `PeopleSpecification` as a parameter:

```
public Page<People> list(@ModelAttribute PeopleSpecification specification, Pagable pageable)
```

And finally use the new inherited method from `JpaSpecificationExecutor` in your `PeopleService` in your controller:

```
Page<People> findAll(Specification<People> specification, Pageable pageable);
```

It's clear that you can alter the implementation of `PeopleSpefication` class to have as many attributes as you want and change the `toPredicate` method logic to return the proper Predicate object.